# MySQL Error from PHP / MySQL upgrade - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, expressionengine

I've recently got this MySQL error:

```
Error SQL query:    
SELECT t.entry_id FROM db_channel_titles AS t LEFT JOIN db_channels ON t.channel_id = db_channels.channel_id LEFT JOIN db_members AS m ON m.member_id = t.author_id WHERE t.entry_id !='' AND t.site_id IN ('1')  AND t.entry_date < 1462934343 AND (t.expiration_date = 0 OR t.expiration_date > 1462934343) AND t.status = 'open' ORDER BY FIELD(t.entry_id, )  LIMIT 0, 100
MySQL said:   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')  LIMIT 0, 100' at line 1
```

which I assume is from a PHP or MySQL upgrade.

Two questions:

1. What is the error in the SQL?
2. The PHP framework we're using is an old version of ExpressionEngine (version 2.0) so I'm not sure we can simply hack the SQL. Given that, I'm wondering what the quickest way of fixing the problem is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed - same error message.

Comment: What do you need to do to generate this error?  And do you really mean version 2.0 or just 2?  Version 2 is still getting updated but 2.0 is very long ago and was in fact a public beta. https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html

Answer (score 3):

Well this isn't right

```
ORDER BY FIELD(t.entry_id, )
```

MySql no likes the missing columns,

Comment: So, I guess my question then becomes why has a missing column suddenly arisen in the SQL. I didn't upgrade ExpressionEngine or any related PHP code prior to this error. All that has happened has been PHP or MySQL upgrades.

Comment: could be typo, copy and paste error, or you used a bad example.  This is in the order by clause, so likely you could just remove the `,` trailing comma.  Even just for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with a PHP or MySQL upgrade. You have curly quotes:

```
t.site_id IN (‘1’)
```

in several places.

Comment: Odd - I just copied / pasted from phpMyAdmin. Let me try again.

Comment: @SnowCrash Make sure you get 'em all. I see three spots.

Comment: @SnowCrash Well, `ORDER BY FIELD(t.entry_id, )` looks like it's missing something. Right where it's reporting the issue.